# How can I suppress dead code warnings for a particular platform?

Tags: rust

I have a particular function that is unused on one platform, but I would still like it to be compiled. Is there any way to `#[allow(dead_code)]` for only a particular configuration?

Here's some example code:

```rust
#[ (what do I put here?) ]
fn cross_platform() {
}

#[cfg(windows)]
pub fn windows_only() {
    // Do a cross-platform thing
    cross_platform();
}
```

Is there any way to suppress the dead code warning on non-Windows platforms only?

Comment: The duplicate applied to your question: `#[cfg_attr(windows, allow(dead_code))]`.

Comment: *However*, why not just mark `cross_platform` as `#[cfg(windows)]` as well?